# Hosting FileSystemWatcher Activity in AppFabric

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric, filesystemwatcher

I have multiple workflows - some of them long-running - that all need to be triggered by files created in multiple directories. We will have many more files to process from many more vendors in the future - each with different processing requirements - so I'd prefer not to have to write and manage a bunch of Windows Services hosting all of these workflows. I have written a FileSystemWatcher Activity and it works great from a Console Application. I need to move them to production now, though, and have been trying to get them running in AppFabric. I've tried using a WorkflowServiceHostFactory along with AppFabric's Auto-Start feature but it seems that the WF never starts. Has anyone done anything similar? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've built a system that waits for files to arrive and then processes them through a workflow.

I had several different input points and several different workflows the files could progress through.

I built mine to all run from a single Windows Service and used local hosting of WorkflowApplications.

My detection workflows are not part of my processing workflows.  They hand off the file processing to different workflows.

I have a config file that determines which file detection workflows to start and which workflows they start once a file is detected.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing (at least temporarily); I wrote a Windows Service that manages a collection of Workflow Activities. I was really hoping to find a way to use AppFabric because it seems to manage error handing and tracking more easily than I can writing a custom Windows Service. I'll wait a while longer for an answer specific to AppFabric but if no-one answers, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks for your input!